# Нужны ли эти запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В любой сетевой компании у каждого (,) кто в неё приходит (,) есть одинаковая возможность построить карьеру.

Comment: "Одинаковая возможность" (как и "равная возможность у каждого") - выражение странное. В единственном числе бывает "одна и та же возможность". Правильнее "_у **всех** есть одинаковые возможности_" или просто "_у каждого есть возможность_" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужны обязательно. Они обособляют придаточное предложение.

Основа главного: есть возможность; основа придаточного: кто приходит.

*В любой сетевой компании у каждого, кто в неё приходит, есть одинаковая возможность построить карьеру.*

---

Только, если можно, я бы заменила "одинаковую возможность", на *равную:*

*В любой сетевой компании у каждого, кто в неё приходит, есть равные возможности построить карьеру.*

Но не настаиваю.